# How to recover a long comment in Facebook after it has errored out

Tags: facebook

I typed a very long comment. Then I clicked post. I got a pop up message and it said only 8000 characters allowed. That pop up box had the message and a OK button that is it.

So I click Ok and I came back to my comment screen encircled with a red boundary. At the bottom it says "Try Again". My question is how to recover my 2 hours comment? I don't want to lose it.

I could not find a edit button, I cannot click on the comment box to do ctrl-A, ctrl-C, I am stuck please advice.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that this was a FB lockup issue and there is not easy way out. So I asked my niece to help me and this is what she did:
"Was able to retrieve the the content of my messages eventually with a hack. Opening up the developer tools, I go to the network tab. There is an option to switch the throttling mode (default to "online") "Slow 3G". This slows down the browser page load. Once this is set, clicking on the "retry again" loads the content of my message. Was able to copy to content before the warning message pops up. "
Thanks to her now I have my comment back.